# What file extension should be applied to NSCoder binary file format?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, filenames, file-extension, nscoder

When using `NSCoder` and `NSKeyedArchiver`, I understand the data is stored in binary format. Therefore, what is the most appropriate file extension for a storage file? Many tutorials use .plist, but I believe this should be text property lists ~ key / value pairs.

Comment: Plist data (including such data contained in a .plist file) does not have to be a dictionary and can be in any of the three plist encoding formats. Anything that decodes plists should be able to handle any of the three formats (as NSPropertyListSerialization is), and any application that reads plists should at least check that it has the right kind of root object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would typically use a custom extension.